# Self-Organising Maps and missing data (NAs) in R

Tags: r, missing-data, self-organizing-maps

The SOM algorithm should be able to deal with some datapoints containing NAs: to find their Best Matching Units, it would be possible to compute Euclidean distances with the neurons ignoring the variables which are Not Available. E.g., if datapoint $i$ is such that $x_k^{(i)}=\mathrm{NA}$, then compute its Euliddean distance with neuron $\mathbf{y}^{(j)}$ through $||\mathbf{x}_{-k}^{(i)}-\mathbf{y}_{-k}^{(j)}||$.

In `R`, I usually employ the `kohonen` package to derive a SOM, but it doesn't seem to have this functionality. Do you have some advice to deal with NAs when computing a SOM in R?

Comment: You might want to consider removing cases with NAs before performing the analysis

Comment: IIRC the `supersom` method in the `kohonen` package allows for some NAs. Check the docs, or contact the author Ron Wehrens directly, he's very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `supersom` method of the `kohonen` package allows for some NAs. From the description of `supersom`:

> An extension of `xyf` maps to multiple data layers, possibly with
>   different numbers of variables (though equal numbers of objects). NAs
>   are allowed (see below). A weighted distance over all layers is
>   calculated to determine the winning units during training.

The "see below" I guess refers to the argument `maxNA.fraction`: *the maximal fraction of values that may be NA to prevent the row or column to be removed*. Check the source for the default value.

I have definitely used it with a dataset containing some NAs in some variables, so try it for yourself.